# Implied Volatility from Heston Model

Tags: volatility, heston

When one construct surface for Implied volatilities using `Heston model` from different Strike prices and Maturities, we get a surface where long dated volatilities are smaller than the short dated ones.

Is there any business reason for such shape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely not generally true

`HestonModel`'s behaviour is controlled by several parameters, but looking at the equation for variance in the Heston model we see that the long term vol is determined by the $\theta$ term, variance will tend to equal this because if it goes above the drift pulls it back down, and vice versa (ie. it's mean-reverting).

[image: Heston equations]

So, if initial variance `v0` is lover than $\theta$, long term IV will be higher than short-term IV. Below is a snippet that generates a vol surface demonstrating this

[image: Example Heston surface using the above parameters]

```
import QuantLib as ql
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

def plot_vol_surface(vol_surface, plot_years=np.arange(0.1, 2, 0.1), plot_strikes=np.arange(80, 120, 1)):
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

    X, Y = np.meshgrid(plot_strikes, plot_years)
    Z = np.array([vol_surface.blackVol(float(y), float(x)) 
                  for xr, yr in zip(X, Y) 
                      for x, y in zip(xr,yr) ]
                 ).reshape(len(X), len(X[0]))

    surf = ax.plot_surface(X,Y,Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, linewidth=0.1)

    fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)

spot = 100
rate = 0.0

today = ql.Date(1, 7, 2020)

calendar = ql.NullCalendar()
day_count = ql.Actual365Fixed()
spot_quote = ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(spot))

# Set up the flat risk-free curves
riskFreeCurve = ql.FlatForward(today, rate, day_count)
flat_ts = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(riskFreeCurve)
dividend_ts = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(riskFreeCurve)

# Create new heston model
v0 = 0.01; kappa = 1.0; theta = 0.04; rho = -0.3; sigma = 0.4

heston_process = ql.HestonProcess(flat_ts, dividend_ts, spot_quote, v0, kappa, theta, sigma, rho)
heston_model = ql.HestonModel(heston_process)

# How does the vol surface look at the moment?
heston_handle = ql.HestonModelHandle(heston_model)
heston_vol_surface = ql.HestonBlackVolSurface(heston_handle)

# Plot the vol surface ...
plot_vol_surface(heston_vol_surface)
```

Comment: Thanks. That is what I was looking for justification. Unfortunately, if I search over google, almost everywhere I see that long term vol will fall!

Comment: Blame quantitative easing, not quantitative finance, for that!

Comment: How are these IVs different from what we get directly from Black–Scholes model for each strike and expiration?